# What does "Poser-like" mean?

Tags: coordinates, 3dsmax

The Wavefront OBJ exporter of 3DSMax says it can flip YZ axis. Claiming this is "Poser-like". What does this mean?

And what is the exact transformation if we decide to flip?
Is it simply this?

```
x => x  
y => -z  
z => y
```

UPDATE: related matrix transformation

```
1  0  0  
0  0 -1  
0  1  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coordinate systems can be whatever you decide.  Some common tools use a different coordinate system that you might consider "normal."  Though there are a couple very common coordinate systems, they really can be whatever you want them to be, so the correct transformation could be application-defined.

+Z being "up" is normal for some model editors and tools but in games +Y is generally "up" with +Z being either "going into the screen" (in a left-handed coordinate system, common in Direct3D-based code) or "going away from the screen" (in a right-handed coordinate system, common in OpenGL-based code).  Nothing stops you from making +X up, +Z left, and +Y into the screen; that would be awkward and "weird" to most people, though.

Max can flip the coordinates for you if you want.  You don't generally need it to.  I'm unsure about its OBJ exporter, but you'll generally need to convert the axis yourself anyway.  Using FBX or the exporter plugin API you can figure out which coordinate system the model is using; OBJ has no such feature so you'll need to do the conversion yourself.

I'm afraid I don't have the "default" Max or Poser coordinate systems for OBJs memorized.  Simple trial-and-error should give you the correct coordinate system: make a rough non-symmetrical model of a person or the like, export/import to your game, and see in which way it's flipped or rotated to determine the right transformation matrix to use during model load to get the data into your game's preferred coordinate system.

Comment: Thank you  
In fact, English is not my native language, and I wanted to know what the "poser" word mean, where you say "poser coordinate system"?

Comment: @AntoineLafarge I'm assuming it means the [Poser software](http://poser.smithmicro.com/poser.html).  I could be wrong.  In plain English "Poser" is anything that "poses" as another.  In games it can sometimes be used as a synonym for "actor" especially if animated, but that's not too common.

Comment: Is there a relationship with this software? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poser

Comment: It's possible that the documentation is just describing the coordinate system that Poser uses.  I'm completely guessing here.

Comment: Ok thanks. Anyway it makes sense! :)  I updated the first post, so I think the flip option apply this transformation matrix on the vertices coordinates.